# React Native Navigator - limit the number of backs

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a complex App with many different screens with several forms. The users complain that from time to time it crashes and exits. I assume it can be from too many navigator.pushes so I'm trying to limit the number of backs, but I can't seem to get it working right.

I'm using `immediatelyResetRouteStack` which I call from Navigator onDidFocus prop.

The problem is, if I call it in Navigator onDidFocus prop it triggers a new render and the screen I'm viewing re-renders after about 1 second. I tried also in a generic function that I call whenever I do navigator.push but then it doesn't do the animation and it is very slow to change to a new screen.

Is there a better way to limit the number of backs?

My code:

```
_navigatorOnDidFocus(){

let routes=_navigator.getCurrentRoutes();

if (routes.length > 4){
  let routesCopy = _.cloneDeep(routes);

  let newRoutes = [
    routesCopy[0],
    routesCopy[2],
    routesCopy[3],
    routesCopy[4],
  ];

  _navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack(newRoutes);

}
}
```